# Rails controller skip after_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a controller as follows:

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController

  after_action -> { puts 'Call me only on success' }

  def create
    obj = Obj.create(obj_params)
    if obj.errors.empty?
      render json: obj
    else
      render json: { errors: obj.errors }, status: 422
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a clean way to stop **all** `after_action`s from executing?
Things I know of:

1. Set some kind of instance variable and check it in every `after_action`
2. `render :something and return` doesn't stop `after_action`s
3. raising an error (like `create!`) would work, but I use it when I don't want to return error specifics and still respond with `422`

I'd settle for something like `render :foo and do_not_call_afters`

Comment: Just put the code after `obj.errors.empty?` and before `render json: obj`. Why do you want to put in an `after_action`?

Comment: The `after_action` method is used across multiple actions and controllers and there can be many of them. I've updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: then you can make a private method and call in the success code black for every action. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Different controllers have different `after_action`s defined, I'm looking for a method to stop any and all of them. Something like "render right now and don't care what's after"

Answer (score 7):

You can ask the response if it was successful:

```
after_action :call_me_on_success, if: -> { response.successful? }
```

This passes for all 2XX codes:

```
response.method(:successful?).source
=> "def successful; status >= 200 && status < 300; end"
```

Comment: That's the best answer yet, it still requires the `if` clause in every `after_action` but not much more.

Answer (score -1):

One way to go with check the instance variable:

```
after_action -> { puts 'Call me only on success' } , if: -> { @foo }
```

set it in create method based on your condition.

Comment: I'm looking for a more "global" solution, so I don't have to specify the if clause in every `after_action` and set the variable in every action.